# ¿Cómo eliminar filas en data frames con determinadas características?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un data frame en R y quiero eliminar todas las filas no cumplan una determinada condición (en este caso, si alguien tiene menos de 60 años). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
hr <- c(87, 78, 86, 62, 69, 69, 68, 67, 75, 76)
age <- rep(c(11, 63, 40, 47), c(3, 2, 4, 1))
names(hr) <- age
hr[c(names(hr) < 45)]    
hr2 <- c(hr[c(names(hr)) == 63], hr[c(names(hr)) == 47])
names(hr2) <- c("Juan", "Ana", "Carmen")
data_frame2 <- cbind(names(hr2), data.frame(hr2, row.names = NULL), 
               c(63, 63, 47))
colnames(data_frame2) <- c("name","hr", "age")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

```
data_frame2[data_frame2$age > 60, ] # Atención a la coma y el espacio al final
```

## Explicación

En R `[,]` se usa para hacer subconjuntos, que es el nombre técnico de lo que quieres hacer. Como en este caso estás trabajando con un data.frame, que es una estructura de datos bidimensional (filas y columnas) usas la coma dentro de los corchetes para hacer subconjuntos de filas (primera posición) y columnas (segunda posición). Dejar ese espacio en blanco (o con un espacio, que en R es lo mismo) es el comodín, quiere decir "todo".

`[,]` es muy versátil, puede evaluar números de índice, nombres o vectores lógicos de `TRUE` `FALSE`. Esto último es lo que estamos utilizando en este caso. `data.frame2$age > 60` usa el operador binario `>`, que evalúa la condición (el lado derecho) en el vector (lado izquierdo) y regresa un vector lógico que con `TRUE` cuando se cumplió la condición. `[,]` evalúa ese vector lógico y te regresa un data.frame en el que están solo las filas en las que se cumple la condición, si lo ubicas en la primera posición.

Podrías hacer otro tipo de pruebas lógicas: `==` igual a, `!=` no igual a. También poner más de una condición encadenándolas con `&` u `|`, **y** y **o** lógicos. Por ejemplo, para hacer un subconjunto con los mayores de 60 años y con `hr` diferente a 62:

```
data_frame2[data_frame2$age > 60 & data_frame2$hr != 62, ]
```

Regresa un data.frame que contiene solo la fila de Ana. Simple y potente.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de eliminar, es 1º seleccionar la fila que quieres eliminar:

Ejemplo, vamos a eliminar del data_frame2 a Carmen.

1º paso: Con indexación booleana elijo la fila de Carmen.

```
data_frame2[data_frame2$name == 'Carmen',]
```

Salida:

```
   name hr age
3 Carmen 76  47
```

Ahora en un 2º paso solo tengo que añadir un '!' para toda esa indexación y me devolvera lo opuesto a lo seleccionado (todo lo que name no es Carmen)

```
data_frame2[!(data_frame2$name == 'Carmen'),]
```

Salida:

```
  name hr age
1 Juan 62  63
2  Ana 69  63
```

Ahora introduzco esa nueva indexación de nuevo en mi data_frame2 y ya tengo fuera la fila que quiero:

```
data_frame2 <- data_frame2[!(data_frame2$name == 'Carmen'),]
```

Para el ejemplo de eliminar a todas las personas < 60 años

```
data_frame2 <- data_frame2[!(data_frame2$age < 60),]
```

ó

```
data_frame2 <- data_frame2[(data_frame2$age > 60),]
```

La indexación booleana es un método muy potente tanto R como python, utilizala siempre que puedes para ahorrar bucles (for, while, etc...)

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Querido blog,
tengo una pregunta referida a este tema. Funcionaria para una columna entera, es decir, necesito eliminar todas las columnas que tengan en alguna de sus variables el numero -5 o -8. Para ello he escrito este codigo:

df = Data set con valores -5 y -8 en diferentes columnas
dfclean =  El nuevo data set que quiero crear

```
dfclean <- df[!df(df==-5) & (df==-8),]
```

- 

Agradeceria su ayuda,
Saludos,
Victoria